# Where is my Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-apps

I'm getting "Summary of failures for Google Apps Script" emails and I don't have any Apps Scripts in my Drive.  Where can I find any scripts that might be running (or trying to run) that are not in my Drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Summary of failures for Google Apps Script" includes a link to the file holding the related script. Read it carefully.

Comment: Thanks Ruben, that answered my question!